# Example of saving data to firebase database REST API with auth token

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I managed to use the REST APIs for Firebase Realtime database to write some data to my database but I'm doing with this with no authentication turned on.

```
curl -X PUT -d '{ "test": "blah" }' 'https://<project>.firebaseio.com/stuff.json'
```

I'm trying to change my auth rule to be

```
".write": "auth != null"
```

but I can't figure out how to generate an auth token to use in:

```
https://<project>.firebaseio.com/stuff.json?auth=<some token>
```

I'm doing this from a server, so I don't want to use a user's token.

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

Comment: I tried that already but I need an ID token, not a custom token.

When I use a custom token, the server responds with an error saying: Expected an ID token, but was given a custom token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the Database Secrets to get the REST api to work with auth.

```
Project Settings-> Sevice Accounts -> Database Secrets
```

Comment: @ajama  Database Secrets is now deprecated and I think you should use generated tokens with Oauth2.

Comment: it is depreciated now. avoid using secret. use access token.